# Linked list by template type conversion error

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, linked-list

I have just done some feature about linked list while using the template function
s.t. it can deal with both int and string liked list.
When I wanna to insert a value in the specified place (ex 0 ,5 ) insert at 0th position with value 5.
I use val_transport to convey the value I want to insert in linked list and T*head in template function to traverse from the head till the node just before the place I want to insert the specified value.

```
int add_pos, add_int;
string add_str;
void main_function_insert_at()
{

    cout << "Enter the position you want to addnode and its value :";
    if (type)
    {
        node < int> val_transport;
        cin >> add_pos >> add_int;
        val_transport.value = add_int;
        int_head = insert_at(int_head, add_pos, val_transport);
    }
    else
    {
        node <string> val_transport;
        cin >> add_pos >> add_str;
        val_transport.value = add_str;
        str_head = insert_at(str_head, add_pos, val_transport);
    }
}

template < typename T >
T* insert_at(T* head, int pos, T val_transport)
{
    T* cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (type)
    {
        node <int>*newnode=NULL;
        newnode = new node < int > ;
        newnode->value = val_transport.value;
        cur->next = newnode;
        newnode->next = cur->next->next;
    }
    else
    {
        node <string>*newnode=NULL;
        newnode = new node < string > ;
        newnode->value = val_transport.value;
        cur->next = newnode;
        newnode->next = cur->next->next;
    }


}
```

However , In my template function , the error like 
is keep showing again and again in the line such as

Error   4   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'node *' to 'node *'
Error   6   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'node *' to 'node *'
Error   3   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'node *' to 'node *'
Error   7   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'node *' to 'node *'
Error   5   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int'

They seems to be the same problems.

I think the template one can accept the other type such as int and string.
But obviously , I am wrong.
Do anyone have the idea? Thanks a lot

**Sorry for my bad English since I am new to CS and from Taiwan :P

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [ask]. It is best to post a [mcve].

Comment: You can't choose a type for the list at runtime.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried operator overloading but also failed, do there exists any other options , thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Templates are instantiated during compilation.

Assuming that you have

```
node<int>* int_head;
node<string>* str_head;
```

your template would instantiate to this if you inserted a `string`:

```
node<string>* insert_at(node<string>* head, int pos, node<string> val_transport)
{
    node<string>* cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (type)
    {
        node <int>*newnode=NULL;
        newnode = new node < int > ;
        newnode->value = val_transport.value;
        cur->next = newnode;
        newnode->next = cur->next->next;
    }
    else
    {
        node <string>*newnode=NULL;
        newnode = new node < string > ;
        newnode->value = val_transport.value;
        cur->next = newnode;
        newnode->next = cur->next->next;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the "true" branch creates a node with the wrong type.

You don't need to check which type of node you're supposed to create – it's the same type as the template parameter, `T`:

```
template <typename T>
T* insert_at(T* head, int pos, T val_transport)
{
    T* cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    T *newnode = new T;
    newnode->value = val_transport.value;
    newnode->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = newnode;
    return head;
}
```

You can also write the template based on the type of the list's contents rather than the type of the list itself.
This makes using a node just for "transport" unnecessary.

```
template <typename T>
node<T>* insert_at(node<T>* head, int pos, T value)
{
    node<T>* cur = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
    {
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    node<T> *newnode = new node<T>;
    newnode->value = value;
    newnode->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = newnode;
    return head;
}

void main_function_insert_at()
{
    cout << "Enter the position you want to add node and its value :";
    if (type)
    {
        cin >> add_pos >> add_int;
        int_head = insert_at(int_head, add_pos, add_int);
    }
    else
    {
        cin >> add_pos >> add_str;
        str_head = insert_at(str_head, add_pos, add_str);
    }
}
```

(You'll want to add some handling of the empty list and out-of-bounds indexing.)

Comment: thanks a lot :D it works, but what is the difference between 
template <typename T>  node<T>* and template < typename T >
T*  i think the latter one is more general one to accept all the "self-made"type pointer since it is a template , but the former one hmmm. 
I got no idea :(

Comment: It helps so much :D ,Today I rewrite my linked list program with all template function and it works without error, thanks for your concept teaching :D